# My Objects won't render

Tags: rendering

Well, I make Minecraft Animations and I was moving from Blender 2.69 to Blender 2.70. The version move was successful. It rendered properly n' stuff. I was playing around with nodes and render layers. After a while I took a render. and all of a sudden every thing did not render. Only the things Ia moved into the 2nd object layer which i moved back to the 1st render layer. Now what. I've been stressing, trying to fix the issue but it won't render.
I'm pretty sure that i did not do an accident of some sort but i probably did. The materials are not transparent. The camera distance is way over how far this is because I have other scenes(old copies of this new one) that still render. Help!

It exists in the 3D view-port but not in the render :( Help?

This is all that renders

[image]

That sucks

3D view-port of what it is actually meant to look like
[image]

Another render
[image]

What is actually meant to be, with the render layers panel
[image]

Here is the node editor, pretty simple because i usually do the compositing after the animation is done.
[image]

Notes: When i was taking a snip of the view-port, i changed it to render view and it was all invisible. Also the image above is set on the last layer but even if i set it to the one with all the objects nothing would render

Answer : Everybody don't worry i found the problem, apparenttly all items were restricted to render for some reason. Not sure why. It might have been when i was playing around with the new flight system(Shift+F) i pressed (W) and accidently pressed Restrict Render Unselected. Anyways this problem has been solved, what do I do?

Comment: Is it possible you could upload the .blend (or at least enough of it so that the issue is apparent)? There are many possible causes and it's hard to guess what might be the issue in your case without more info (best gotten from a .blend).

Comment: At the very least, post screenshots of your render layers panel and tell or show us what's in each one. Check the focal length of your render camera also.

Comment: The file is just too large and with my internet, it's not gonna happen. I may upload more snapshots though. The focal length is 15.66 Blender units

Comment: Have you tried recalculating the normals(`CTRL-N`)?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your compositing node editor setup?

Comment: What are your material/texture UV settings? Is it possible they got messed up somehow?

Comment: Everybody don't worry i found the problem, apparenttly all items were restricted to render for some reason. Not sure why. It might have been when i was playing around with the new flight system(Shift+F) i pressed (W) and accidently pressed Restrict Render Unselected. Anyways this problem has been solved, what do I do?

Comment: The post will remain closed as you have identified the problem and it's a localized issue that doesn't really correlate with the question.